# Generalizing Intermediate Value theorem using sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Let $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous, and $X$ be connected.

Prove that for any 2 points $a, b \in X$ and every number $y_0$ lying between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, there exists a point $x_0 \in X$ such that $f(x_0)=y_0$.

---

Thoughts:

Of course using letting another functions works like:

Suppose $f(a)<f(b)$ such that $f(a)<y_0<f(b)$

Let $g(X)=f(X) - y_0$, such that

$g(a)=f(a)-y_0 <0$

$g(b)=f(b)-y_0 >0$

then for a $x_0$ which $a<x_0<b$, there must be a point $f(x_0)=y_0$

however I still haven't used the fact that $X$ is connected. How do I connect it with the concepts of sets????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** If not, then $X = f^{-1} [ ( - \infty , y_0 ) ] \cup f^{-1} [ ( y_0 , + \infty ) ]$.

---

If $f(x) \neq y_0$ for all $x \in X$, then surely for each $x \in X$ either $f(x) < y_0$ (so $x \in f^{-1} [ ( - \infty , y_0 ) ]$, or $f(x) > y_0$ (so $x \in f^{-1} [ ( y_0 , + \infty ) ]$).

The answers to the following two questions should give a complete solution:

- What does the continuity of $f$ say what about these two sets?
- What does the fact that $y_0$ *is strictly between* $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ say about these two sets?

Comment: um... a little bit more please since I dont really know how do u come up with it?

Comment: @Paul: I've added a bit to the answer.  I hope it directs you to the whole solution.